# how to create multiple fields, having their number?

Tags: reactjs

After some transformations i get the number of fields that need to be rendered

```
let InputsMaker=(props)=> {
    let da={};
    for (let i = 0; i < props.count; i++) {
        da+=<input key={i}>da</input>;
    }
    return da
};
```

but after executing the functions of this component, react renders the specified number of "object Object". What needs to be fixed in the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Map function also.

```
let InputsMaker=(props) => Array(props.count || 0).fill(1).map((val,i)=>(<input key={i}>da</input>))
```

Comment: @derty14 interesting that you accepted this answer - I'd question the readability, and the fact that an array will be created each time this component renders just to throw it away again, in a bid to get it into one line. Also, it doesn't actually answer your question either...